# How will I fix my android studio project? whenever I click the buttonCal button, it restarts

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button buttonCal = findViewById(R.id.buttonCal);
        final EditText Salary = findViewById(R.id.Salary);
        final TextView textView5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        buttonCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int sal = Integer.parseInt(Salary.getText().toString());
                textView5.setText(+ sal);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I'm new to android studio, pls help...

here's the errrors...

02-22 22:14:53.564 13771-13889/com.example.dell.caltax E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (2/0x47/0x48/0x46)
02-22 22:14:53.564 13771-13889/com.example.dell.caltax E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (540/960/1)
02-22 22:14:56.460 13771-13889/com.example.dell.caltax E/libEGL: cache file failed CRC check

Comment: post the error logs

Comment: Are you sure it's R.id.Salary not R.id.salary?

Comment: pretty sure it's R.id.Salary... I'm really sorry if I suck at this... I just want help...

Comment: Try this 'textView5.setText(""+ sal);'

Answer (score 0):

We can not set `TextView` to `int`, it should be `String`.

Use below code :

```
 buttonCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int sal = Integer.parseInt(Salary.getText().toString());
           // textView5.setText("Salary"+ sal);
             textView5.setText(""+ sal);
        }
    });
```

or,

```
 buttonCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

          textView5.setText(Salary.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```